# Enhance GS Script to Update specific column values to another Sheet (specific columns) if row ID matches in both sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

1. In GS script I am trying to update the values from the "Payroll" Sheet to the "Log" Sheet.
2. Based on the criteria, If Payroll Sheet A**3**:A matches to Log Sheet A**2**:A
   in the Payroll sheet first 2 Rows are headers, and in Log Sheet first row is a header.
3. Only specified columns/cells must be updated.
4. given sample code is working, But **VERY SLOW**.

```
function updateLogSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var payrollSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Payroll");
  var logSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Log");

  // Get the Emp.code from A1 of the Payroll sheet
  var empCode = payrollSheet.getRange("A1").getValue();

  // Get the values in the Date list from A3:A of the Payroll sheet
  var logIds = payrollSheet.getRange("A3:A").getValues().flat().filter(Boolean);

  var logValues = logSheet.getRange("A2:AH").getValues();
  logValues = logValues.filter(function (x) {
    return !(x.every(element => element === (undefined || null || '')))
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < logValues.length; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j < logIds.length; j++) {
      if (logIds[j] === logValues[i][0]) {
        var payrollIndex = j + 3;
        if (logValues[i][2] == empCode && payrollIndex !== -1) {
          var rowIndex = i + 2; // Add 2 because the range starts at A2
          if (rowIndex != -1) {
            // Update the cells in the Log sheet
            logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 2).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("B" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // Date

            logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 28).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("AB" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // + symbol
           
            logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 31).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("AE" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // empty        
            
            logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 34).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("AH" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // Manual Hrs Adjust        

            logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 7).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("G" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 1st ClockIN TIME 
            logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 8).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("H" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 1-IN-Loc
            logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 9).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("I" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 1-Activity
            logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 11).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("J" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 1-Project         
            logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 13).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("K" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 1-Note

            logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 23).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("L" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 2-IN-TIME
            logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 24).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("M" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 2-IN-Loc
            logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 25).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("N" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 2-Activity
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 27).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("O" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 2-Project
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 29).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("P" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 2-Note     

        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 38).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("Q" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 3-IN-TIME        
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 40).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("R" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 3-IN-Loc
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 41).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("S" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 3-Activity
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 43).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("T" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 3-Project
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 44).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("U" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 3-Note

        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 15).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("V" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 1-OUT-TIME        
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 16).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("W" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 1-OUT-Loc
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 17).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("X" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 1-OUT-Activity
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 21).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("Y" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 1-OUT-Note

        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 31).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("Z" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 2-OUT-TIME
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 32).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("AA" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 2-OUT-Loc
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 33).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("AB" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 2-OUT-Activity
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 37).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("AC" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 2-OUT-Note

        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 47).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("AD" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 3-OUT-TIME
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 48).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("AE" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 3-OUT-Loc
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 49).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("AF" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 3-OUT-Activity
        logSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 53).setValue(payrollSheet.getRange("AG" + payrollIndex).getValue()); // 3-OUT-Note

           } 
        }
        payrollIndex = -1;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Attached link and Sample Sheet image for reference

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UiwpNM2S0aeo4QinbEi-NqyPkGFVoZobqareeAOCsHs/edit?usp=sharing

[image: Log Sheet]

[image: Payroll Sheet]

these are the exact columns to be updated

Payroll to Log

B to B

G to G

I to J

J to K

K to M

L to W

M to X

N to Y

O to AA

P to AC

Q to AL

R to AN

S to AO

T to AQ

U to AS

V to O

W to P

X to Q

Y to U

Z to AE

AA to AF

AB to AG

AC to AK

AD to AU

AE to AV

AF to AW

AG to BA

---

thank you :)

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you :) it works exactly with the requirements 

Comment: And it's fast as well. Thank you :)

Comment: But one thing it is not matching with ID code 
Payroll (A3:A) = Log (A2:A) then update the value with the ID listed row

Comment:  In the line const obj = srcValues.reduce((o, e) => (o[e[0]] = e, o), {});, it creates an object (obj) where the keys are the values in the first column of the srcValues array (which comes from the Payroll sheet), and the values are the entire rows.

Comment: About your new issue of `In the line const obj = srcValues.reduce((o, e) => (o[e[0]] = e, o), {});, it creates an object (obj) where the keys are the values in the first column of the srcValues array (which comes from the Payroll sheet), and the values are the entire rows.`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new issue. But, I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about the detail of your new issue? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: thanks for asking. Just want to know, that the given modified script checks whether the payroll (A3:A)  matches with Log (A2:A).

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Just want to know, that the given modified script checks whether the payroll (A3:A) matches with Log (A2:A).`, in my proposed script, column "A" of both sheets is checked. And, "Log" sheet is updated by checking the same value of column "A". If I misunderstood your reply, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function sample() {
  // Ref: https://tanaikech.github.io/2022/07/04/converting-a1notation-to-gridrange-and-vice-versa-using-google-apps-script-without-any-scopes/
  const columnLetterToIndex_ = letter => [...letter.toUpperCase()].reduce((c, e, i, a) => (c += (e.charCodeAt(0) - 64) * Math.pow(26, a.length - i - 1)), -1);

  // These values are from your question.
  const conversion = [["B", "B"], ["G", "G"], ["I", "J"], ["J", "K"], ["K", "M"], ["L", "W"], ["M", "X"], ["N", "Y"], ["O", "AA"], ["P", "AC"], ["Q", "AL"], ["R", "AN"], ["S", "AO"], ["T", "AQ"], ["U", "AS"], ["V", "O"], ["W", "P"], ["X", "Q"], ["Y", "U"], ["Z", "AE"], ["AA", "AF"], ["AB", "AG"], ["AC", "AK"], ["AD", "AU"], ["AE", "AV"], ["AF", "AW"], ["AG", "BA"]];

  const converted = conversion.map(e => e.map(f => columnLetterToIndex_(f)));
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Payroll");
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Log");
  const srcValues = srcSheet.getRange("A3:AG" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const obj = srcValues.reduce((o, e) => (o[e[0]] = e, o), {});
  const dstRange = dstSheet.getRange("A2:BA" + dstSheet.getLastRow());
  const values = dstRange.getValues().map(e => {
    const ar = obj[e[0]];
    if (ar) {
      converted.forEach(([a, b]) => e[b] = ar[a] || null);
    }
    return e;
  });
  dstRange.setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, an array is created and the created array is put into the destination sheet. By this, I thought that the process cost might be able to be reduced a little.

#### Note:

- The values of `conversion` is from your question. If you want to change this, please modify the values.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)